# In Kafka Connect, how to connect with multiple kafka clusters?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I set the kafka connect cluster in distributed mode and I wanna get connections with multiple kafka CLUSTERS, not just multiple brokers.
Target brokers can be set with `bootstrap.servers` in `connect-distributed.properties`.
So, at first, I set broker1 from kafka-cluster-A like below:

```
bootstrap.servers=broker1:9092
```

Absolutely, it worked well.

And then, I added broker2 from kafka-cluster-B like below:

```
bootstrap.servers=broker1:9092,broker2:9092
```

So, these two brokers are in the different clusters.
And this didn't work at all.
Without any error, it was just stuck and there was no answer with the request like creating connector through the REST API.

How can I connect with multiple kafka clusters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only connect a Kafka Connect worker to one Kafka cluster.

If you have data on different clusters that you want to handle with Kafka Connect then run multiple Kafka Connect worker processes.

Comment: Thanks! decided to use ReplicatorSourceConnector to ingest data from multiple kafka clusters. With this connector, I can copy topics from multiple different clusters to my own kafka cluster and then sink connectors consume those copied ones. So, the kafka connect cluster connects my kafka cluster only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Connect on the source cluster (rather than the destination), this is what is needed:

1. Set `bootstrap.servers` to source server in connect-distributed-worker.properties
2. Initiate actual mirroring via the Connect REST API:

```
curl --noproxy "*" -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' http://localhost:8083/connectors -d'{
    "name": "MirrorSourceConnector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
        "replication.factor": "1",
        "source.cluster.alias": "site1",
        "target.cluster.alias": "cloud",
        "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:29092",
        "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:49092",
        "topics": ".*",
        "emit.checkpoints.interval.seconds": "1",
        "emit.heartbeats.interval.seconds": "1",
        "sync.topic.acls.enabled": "false",
        "refresh.topics.interval.seconds": "4",
        "producer.override.bootstrap.servers":"localhost:49092"
    }
    }'
```

By far, the MOST IMPORTANT THING, is:

**"producer.override.bootstrap.servers":"localhost:49092"**

which actually causes source -> target replication to work. I don't know why  `"target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:49092"` doesn't work like it should. But this solution works. Without this snippet, replication will just replicate topics on source cluster with a "site1" prefix and not do anything with the target.

This isn't documented anywhere in the OSS docs, I found mention of it here in this [blog post](https://medium.com/@ankochem/tutorial-mirror-maker-2-0-basic-configuration-d0d1cbca695d) as well as on this Confluent page ["Running Replicator on the Source Cluster"](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/multi-dc-deployments/replicator/replicator-run.html#running-crep-on-the-source-cluster)

(This solution was tested on Apache Kafka Connect 3.2.0 and/or `cp-kafka:7.2.1` Docker image)